# Showing a WPF loading message until after UI finishes updating

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, uirefreshcontrol

In my application, I'm allowing the user to select an item from a tree of items in the left side, and when that item gets selected, I should update the UI on the right side. Now, during the update of the UI (which might take a second or two), I display a "Please Wait" message to indicate that the application is currently working via a background thread.

When the loading of the UI is completed I wish to make this "Please Wait" window disappear, but the problem now is that the data fetching process ends quite fast, which makes the "Please Wait" window to disappear, but since the UI hasn't yet updated, the app gets stuck for a second and then, only after UI was updated, it gets released.

How can I send a message to remove the "Please Wait" message window only **after** UI has completed its work and refreshed? (I use GalaSoft's `Messenger` class to send messages through my application)

**EDIT:**
This is my code for reference:

```
// Show the "Please wait window" while running the long operation
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LoadingHelper.ShowProgressBar());

t.ContinueWith((priorTask) =>
                    {
                        // DOING SOME HEAVY LIFTING WORK HERE

                        // TRYING TO FORCE THE UI TO REFRESH
                        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() => { }));
                    });
t.ContinueWith((antecedent) => LoadingHelper.HideProgressBar()); // Make the loading window disappear
```

**EDIT2:**

I'm aware of async programming. My question was mainly since my "heavy lifting" work is done and the "please wait" message is removed, but the UI is refreshing to reflect the results from the heavy work and that is taking a few moments. I want to keep the "Please Wait" message on the screen until all UI has done loading (maybe by using the `Loaded` event on the control?)

Comment: have you used backgroundworker?

Comment: I've edited my question to show exactly what I'm currently doing. I'm using `Task`s to multithread my work

Comment: A background worker can't access the UI so you can't use it for sending notifications to the user or updating the UI in any way. Your background worker thread should be doing the heavy data fetching and not the other way around.

Comment: Are you using `ObservableCollection` to update/refresh the UI? If so, you should try to call the `HideProgressBar` method after all Collections have been updated (because ObservableCollections will be bound to UI controls).

Comment: No collections are in play here. What this code does in my code is basically set the current "page" of the application to a certain `ViewModel`, the application responds to this by changing the current view to that who fits the selected ViewModel.

Comment: @JonathanPerry, Not completely sure if it fits your requirement, but I had a similar requirement and I followed the articles in this link and some of my own logic: [Navigation With MVVM](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)

Comment: @VS1 This is the exact same article I used to create my initial application, and this is the same way I use to display my pages. I don't know why the UI takes a long time to update. I'm using Visifire's charts, maybe that's why...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of forcing a render, why not try to wait for rendering to finish and dispatch?

Maybe get rid of the line, and do

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => LoadingHelper.HideProgressBar()), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null)
```

at the exact line you are trying a force render?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is Asynchronous Programming

Have a read of this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

This helps with this exact situation where you do not want to block the UI (and thus a bad reflection on the UI for the user), but need work doing in the background.

There are some usable examples in that article.

Create your Task to do the heavy work.

Create an async void method to call the task and await it.

Before you await the task, show your busy message > await the task > when the task is complete remove the busy message.

The important thing here is that you are taking away the load on the UI thread and giving it to another. At the moment is sounds like your UI thread is doing more processing than it needs to.

Comment: Thanks Gavin. I'm aware of async programming, that's why I use TPL. But in my case the work is done and then, when the UI is updated it takes a few seconds to load all the controls (with graphs and animations). My question was that I wanted to show the progress bar window until all UI was done loading, not just after my "heavy lifting" work was completed. I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: I'd be suspicious of the 'Stuck UI' you mentioned after the heavy work is done. Unless is a very complicated UI; most UI updates (when any other work is properly managed to not block the UI thread) are very fast and happen in milliseconds. Giving a 'busy' indicator to show UI is loading is only adding to the work the UI Thread has to do.